# I want to add some error percentage to the output of max-pooling layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, max-pooling

I want to add some error percentage (relative error) to the output of max-pooling layer in CNN. I am using max pooling layer from keras.
Below is the code

```
i = Input(shape=x_train[0].shape)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(i)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
```

How can I add some errors to the output of this layer?
I want to add some fraction of the original output.
e.g. if x is my original output, I want my output to be x+ some fraction of (x).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add noise to `x`, e.g. [`GaussianNoise`](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/gaussian_noise/)

Comment: I did that but I want only positive values to be added and I want to add some fraction of the output.

Comment: _x+ some fraction of (x)_ is not noise, you are adding a deterministic quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add a fraction of the input, you can just use `Add`:

```
x = K.layers.Add()([x, 1/4 * x])
```

for example:

```
input = K.layers.Input(shape=(5,))
x = K.layers.Add()([input, 1/4 * input])
model = K.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[x])
model(np.ones((1,5)))
#<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25]], dtype=float32)>
```

However this is not noise, and the affine transformation after this layer will vanish what you have done, infact:

```
A(x+ 1/4x)+b
= A(5/4x)+b
= 5/4 * A(x)+b
```

so you are not adding any "additional expressivity" to your network

if you clarify what noise (wrt to a *a fraction of the input*) you want, I'll fix my answer

Comment: Basically, I want to add let's say 5% of the original value to the output of the max-pooling layer.
If my output of my max-pooling layer was let's say 2, I want it to be 2+(0.1)(which is 5 % of 2)=2.1,
so the new o/p is 
x + fraction of x that's what I want

Comment: @shaq_m as i said, this is not noise, you are adding a well defined quantity to your output, and the code that I've posted does exactly that, just with 1/4, but you can change it to 1/20 if you want 0.05%

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. So using the code that you have posted I am adding a well-defined value to output of max-pooling layer.

Comment: yes, you are doing `x + 1/smt * x`, try it and let me know

Comment: It will work but what about the second part that you have mentioned regarding affine transformation? Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @shaq_m idk what's you preparation in math, but with affine transformation i mean the "Wx+b" part of the layers.... and I just stated that this "adding a 5% to the output" does not increase how "powerful" is your network, since 2 affine transformations, are just as powerful as one (I've posted the calculus, and you can see that the last one is just a single affine transformation)... is like having 2 subsequent linear layer... they are as powerful as a single linear layer

Comment: @shaq_m you're welcome, if you have additional questions, feel free to ask, and if this solves your initial question, feel free to mark is as correct